# Saving related entity in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a problem with saving form values from two domain classes

One class is

```
 class Ip {

String inetAddress
String dns
String os



String toString(){
    "${inetAddress}"
}

Hoster hoster

static constraints = {
     ....
```

and the second one is just

```
  class Hoster {

    static HOSTER_OPTIONS = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
String name;

String toString(){
    "${name}"
}

List ips = new ArrayList()
static hasMany = [ips : Ip]

    static constraints = {
    name(unique: true, blank: false, inList: HOSTER_OPTIONS)
}
```

I have a Controller where I handle the data from a form

```
def systems = new Ip()  
systems.inetAddress = params.ip
systems.dns = params.dns
systems.os = params.os

systems.hoster.name = params.hoster
def result = systems.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

But I didn't get it managed that the data is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not associating correctly your domain classes in the controller:

```
systems.hoster.name = params.hoster
```

Instead of setting the name, you need to set the instance that exists in the database:

```
systems.hoster = Hoster.findByName(params.hoster)
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I get an different error: Class:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationExceptionMessage:Column 'hoster_id' cannot be null

Comment: Your Hoster is already in the database? `findByName` returns anything?

Comment: Yes, the hoster is already in the database. findByName returns the name if it exists otherwise null.

Comment: I know what findByName does, my question was about what it returns in your context: `Hoster.findByName(params.hoster)`. Also, I had a typo in my answer, make sure that you're using `params.hoster`, I writed "patams".

Comment: I've seen the typo and fixed it on my side. In my context it returns the hoster name when it is in the database. I did a short test to verify: def test = Hoster.findByName("Test") <- returns null as the hoster does not exist, when I use params.hoster and the hoster exists already it returns the name. Shouldn't it return the object?

Comment: This seems a bug. When I remove the hasMany relation it works